# How to detect transition to landscape when you have more then one viewcontroller

Tags: swift, autolayout, landscape-portrait, viewwilltransitiontosize

I have a small app with only 4 view controllers and I want to change the layout when the user transitions to/from landscape.  I figured out how to check for landscape, but the function lives in one viewController class and I am not clear how to get my other viewControllers to take action when the viewWillTransition fires.  Do I put a version of that override function in each view controller class to do things specific to it?  When I tried putting the override in both classes after a segue they BOTH fired and didn't feel like "right way to do it" and so I wanted to ask the experts.

Using the code below on app start I set a global bool for whether it is in landscape and I use viewWillTransition to detect changes.

```
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    print("Will Transition to size \(size) from super view size \(self.view.frame.size)")

    if (size.width > self.view.frame.size.width) {
        print("Landscape")
        inLandscapeMode = true
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
        inLandscapeMode = false
    }

    if (size.width != self.view.frame.size.width) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // DO SOMETHING LIKE reload a Table/Collection view to ensure no dequeued cells have old constraints... self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
func setUpFormatting(){
    let size = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    print("On App Start size \(size)")
    if size.width > size.height {
        print("Landscape")
        inLandscapeMode = true
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
        inLandscapeMode = false
    }
}
```

All of

Answer (score 0):

You can get the device orientation in every view controller and setup views by that value

```
if UIDevice.current.orientation == .portrait {

} else if UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft || UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeRight {

}
```

Comment: I have a variable set and always know if I am in landscape/portrait, I want to adjust layout when it changes. My app has a view controller with an imageView taking up whole screen aspect fitted. In portrait there is almost always empty space for an image description, but in landscape description is on top of the pic.  That view controller is segue'ed to from a view controller for sign in which contains viewWillTransition to manage its format.  When a user is logged on and flips the phone I want to show/hide that image description on image one. Do I just put the override func in both classes?